# Pass dynamic div id into javascript without links and hovers

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, html

i have multiple dynamic div ids in a while loop, this div id is to be used in  JavaScript to display a radial progress bar. my problem is that although i have unique ids i cant pass this unique ids to my JavaScript to show the different radial progress for each. i have tried using div class but that just repeats the last id of the loop in all progress bars. i don't want to use links or hovers to get the unique id as i want the JavaScript to fire on page load. How can i make each div in my while loop display the progress the progress bar correctly.

**sample.php**

```
<?php
    ..................................
    while($obj = $getcDetails->fetch()){
        //div that displays radial progress bar
        echo '
            <div class="page" style="color:#000000;">
                <div id="progress-pie-chart'.$Id.'" data-percent="'.$cId.'">
                    <div class="ppc-progress">
                        <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="ppc-percents">
                <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
                    <span>%</span>
                </div>
            </div></div></div>';
?>
```

**sample.js**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart'),//add dynamic id here to display multiple progress bar unique to that div
    percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
    deg = 360*percent/100;
    if (percent > 50) {
        $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
    }
    $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    $('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
});
</script>
```

Any help or guide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to know the id?  You need to loop over the $ppc in order to process them one at a time.  Especially since you are basing the following logic off of the percent, which I'm assuming is different for each one, and not all of them are > 50

Comment: Also the markup that you showed us you are generating in the loop looks incomplete.  It is missing two closing div tags.

Comment: @Taplar Would this require the JavaScript to be  inside the loop? if so can you show me how to add JavaScript function in a PHP loop, I've been unsuccessful in the past

Comment: @Taplar, Thanks. it was a typo while copying my code here, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can base this logic off of just a class.  Given that the progress fill and percents are children of the progress-pie-chart, you can find the ones you need to change, with a contextual lookup.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.progress-pie-chart').each(function(){
    var $ppc = $(this)
      , percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent'))
      , deg = 360*percent/100;
      
    if (percent > 50) {
      $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
    }
    
    $ppc.find('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    $ppc.find('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and answer, it works now